# How do I exit iedit mode with enter?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to use my regular keybinding to enter iedit (M--), but I want to exit iedit with a simple press of enter. How do I do that?

I guess I should add a hook to my .emacs for iedit-mode, but reading the C-h f iedit ENTER it seems that no such thing exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom command and bind it to `RET` in the keymap used by `iedit-mode`:

```lisp
(require 'iedit)

(defun quit-iedit-mode ()
  "Turn off iedit-mode."
  (interactive)
  (iedit-mode -1))

(define-key iedit-mode-keymap (kbd "RET") 'quit-iedit-mode)
```

With this in place, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> turns off `iedit-mode`.

Comment: Evil people might want to add (evil-mode 1) after the (iedit-mode -1). Thanks, btw!